# PayPal Payflow HTML Integration with PayPal created buttons?

Tags: html, payflowlink

So I hope I don't sound to noob here.  I've created all required buttons via the customers paypal account.  I signed them up with PayFlow Checkout as they have a gateway that they want to use bc it's with their business bank, it's a First Date Merchant Account.

The payflow checkout is the free version for now.  I have also saved and published the integrated checkout page.

How or what am I missing that needs to occur on their product page for the PayFlow process to be used?

I've gone through the PDF for developers but maybe I am not understanding something. I thought it was a simple fix to the buttons or some code snippet I paste in the header area.

EDIT - I do have the sandbox accounts created however maybe I'm not sure of what needs to happen next.

Buttons and current paypal cart located [here](http://www.misterkoool.com/test/purchase.html).

Please be kind and give me any tips on what am I missing.

Keith